# Spark-submit is not using the protobuf version of my project

Tags: maven, apache-spark, dependencies, protocol-buffers

In my work project, I use spark-submit to launch my application into a yarn cluster. I am quite new to Maven projects and pom.xml use, but the problem I seem to be having is that hadoop is using an older version of google protobuf (2.5.0) than the internal dependencies I'm importing at work (2.6.1).

The error is here:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
com/google/protobuf/LazyStringList.getUnmodifiableView()Lcom/google/protobuf/LazyStringList;
(loaded from file:/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/spark2/jars/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar 
by sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@8b6f2bf7) 
called from class protobuf.com.mycompany.group.otherproject.api.JobProto$Query
```

Since I'm not quite sure how to approach dependency issues like this, and I can't change the code of the internal dependency that uses 2.6.1, I added the required protobuf version as a dependency to my project, as well:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Unfortunately, this hasn't resolved the issue. When the internal dependency (which does import 2.6.1 on its own) tries to use its proto, the conflict occurs.

Any suggestions on how I could force the usage of the newer, correct version would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I found the Maven Shade Plugin to be the answer. I shaded my company's version of protobufs, deployed our service as an uber jar, and the conflict was resolved.